# How to join two tables based on Grouping of 1 column in both the tables

Tags: sql-server

I have come up a situation which is not easy to explain in sentence so i will go ahead and give the complete scenario here.

I have one result set like the below :-

[image]

It shows **header_equipment_id(s)** in a group of **jil_equipment_id,relationship_name,cell_group**.. For example 3159398,4622903 lies in one group.

The other result set is given below, This is the table where i want to update 3 columns namely **Is_Applicable_Price,prc_content_rid,prc_type_name**

[image]

If you notice clearly, You will find the same **header_equipment_id** column here. If you group it with the result found above, You will find 3 different groups for. But out of those 3 groups, one group is red, It is red because they belong to different **cell_group**/**relationship_name**.

**

- Yellow and green are passed scenario and Red, Blue are fail.

**

I want to update the columns **Is_Applicable_Price,prc_content_rid,prc_type_name** if the Group of **header_equipment_id(s)** fall under the same **cell_group** and **relationship_name**.

So the final result set would look something like below -

[image]

Please help me with any inputs if possible. It's a situation where i know one single query won't work. But i will need to have multiple Temp tables for the transformation. But this is the shortest i have came across.

I am using Microsoft sql server 2012.

Please help. Even a small hint would be of great help to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have rule for deciding the update values for Is_Applicable_Price,prc_content_rid,prc_type_name?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the only thing the 2 tables have in common is that a cell_group can have a one or more rows of header_equipment_id. If we can generate a unique value based on header_equipment_id then we can join the 2 tables on this value. Note I have used a simple division , you may wish to check that this method is unique enough for your purposes.

```
 /*create table a 
    (jil_equimentid int,relationship_name varchar(20),header_equipment_id int,
    smart_equipment_id int,cell_group int,new_price_flag int,is_applicable_price int,prc_content_rid int,prc_type_name varchar(20))
    truncate table a
    insert into a values
    (1282977,'default',3159398,1282977,3,1,1,106347924,'New Price'),
    (1282977,'default',4622903,1262578,3,1,1,106347924,'New Price'),
    (1282977,'default',1659861,1282977,6,1,1,106347925,'New Price'),
    (1282977,'default',4622904,1282977,6,1,1,106347925,'New Price')
    go

drop table t
go
create table t 
(jil_equimentid int,relationship_name varchar(20),header_equipment_id int,
smart_equipment_id int,cell_group int,new_price_flag int,is_applicable_price int,prc_content_rid int,prc_type_name varchar(20))
truncate table t
insert into t values
(1282977,'128297711111 default',4622903,1282977,1,1,null,null,null),
(1282977,'128297711211 default',3159398,1262578,2,1,null,null,null),
(1282977,'128297712111 default',4622904,1282977,4,1,null,null,null),
(1282977,'128297712211 default',1659861,1282977,5,1,null,null,null),
(1282977,'128297711101 default',3159398,1262578,1,1,null,null,null),
(1282977,'128297711101 default',4622903,1282977,1,1,null,null,null),
(1282977,'default'             ,3159398,1262578,2,1,null,null,null),
(1282977,'default'             ,4622903,1282977,2,1,null,null,null),
(1282977,'128297711101 default',1659861,1262577,3,1,null,null,null),
(1282977,'128297711101 default',4622904,1282977,3,1,null,null,null),
(1282977,'default'             ,1659861,1262577,4,1,null,null,null),
(1282977,'default'             ,4622904,1262577,4,1,null,null,null)
*/

DROP  TABLE #TEMPA;
;WITH CTE AS
(SELECT  a.cell_group,
        sum(a.header_equipment_id / 10000000.0000)  uniqueval
from    a
group   by a.cell_group
)
SELECT  DISTINCT CTE.UNIQUEVAL ,IS_APPLICABLE_PRICE ,PRC_CONTENT_RID ,PRC_TYPE_NAME
INTO    #TEMPA
FROM    CTE
JOIN    A ON A.CELL_GROUP = CTE.CELL_GROUP

;WITH   CTE AS
(
SELECT  t.relationship_name,t.cell_group,
        sum(t.header_equipment_id / 10000000.0000)  uniqueval
from    t
group   by t.relationship_name,t.cell_group having count(*) > 1
)
SELECT  T.*,CTE.UNIQUEVAL,ta.*
FROM    CTE
JOIN    T ON T.RELATIONSHIP_NAME = CTE.RELATIONSHIP_NAME AND T.CELL_GROUP = CTE.CELL_GROUP
join    #tempa ta on ta.uniqueval = cte.uniqueval
```

Comment: Hey, The relationship_name and cell_group can be different in both the table so can't join on the basis of them...!

Comment: Is there a maximum of 2 rows per cell group?

Comment: Nope, It is not fixed :(

Comment: Yes, Any approach you can suggest ? Just the approach

Comment: I have rewritten the solution please have a look.